# Centered horizontal Listview.builder non scrollable Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview, non-scrolling

i have days trying to build a centered horizontal listview fixed (non scrollable), I dont know if maybe Im going the wrong way or that its not posible, I have search a lot with any result. Please send me in the correct way. I would appreciate, thank you for your time!

what Im looking for in the green rectangle[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtUCg.png)]

I tried play around with container sizedbox etc.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/models/survey_model.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/widgets/radio_buttom.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class prueba extends StatefulWidget {
  prueba({super.key, required this.survey});
  int answer = 0;
  late Future<Survey> survey;
  @override
  State<prueba> createState() => _pruebaState();
}

class _pruebaState extends State<prueba> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<Survey>(
              future: widget.survey,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 70,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: 5,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                CustomRadio(
                                    groupValue: snapshot
                                        .data!.questions[3].answers![index].value,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      widget.answer = snapshot.data!.questions[3]
                                          .answers![index].value;
                                      setState(() {});
                                    },
                                    value: widget.answer),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 34,
                                  width: 56,
                                  child: Text(
                                    snapshot
                                        .data!.questions[3].answers![index].text,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xff000000),
                                        letterSpacing: -0.26,
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try putting **shrinkWrap: true**, and **physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()**, in your **ListView.builder**, this will control whether the list adapts to the size of its contents or expands to take up all the space.

To make them in the center add **mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center**, this will center your row items.

Here I share your same example, I also consider to call your classes with capital letters. You could also consider to assign to itemCount the size of your dynamic list (example: array.length) and not a constant value.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/models/survey_model.dart';
import 'package:healy_app/widgets/radio_buttom.dart';

class Prueba extends StatefulWidget {
  Prueba({super.key, required this.survey});
  int answer = 0;
  late Future<Survey> survey;
  @override
  State<Prueba> createState() => _PruebaState();
}

class _PruebaState extends State<Prueba> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<Survey>(
            future: widget.survey,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 70,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: 5,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              CustomRadio(
                                groupValue: snapshot
                                    .data!.questions[3].answers![index].value,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  widget.answer = snapshot
                                      .data!.questions[3].answers![index].value;
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                                value: widget.answer,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 34,
                                width: 56,
                                child: Text(
                                  snapshot
                                      .data!.questions[3].answers![index].text,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                                      letterSpacing: -0.26,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```